# Why do SFTP Break-In Attempts Show As Local IPs?

Tags: sftp

I have an SFTP server which I'm using to host files. The password is very strong (normal dictionary attacks or cracks will not work). I'm not too worried after reading this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/244614/is-it-normal-to-get-hundreds-of-break-in-attempts-per-day?newreg=a248b7c0a1044da3be5dbdc4b80b75a9). But I noticed something very peculiar. Here's a sample of the logs:

```
input_userauth_request: invalid user administrador [preauth] 
Failed password for invalid user administrador from 10.51.6.91 port 21788 ssh2
```

What? How could the IP be a local IP address? This is an external facing application, so I expect the request to come from an external IP. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the local host has been compromised and is being used as a "pivot point" to attack from the inside.  It may be worth investigating that host further.

It's also possible that an internal user is trying to break into that server.